# Ui Grid handleWindowResize in RTL not working

Tags: angular-ui-grid

I resized my page within ui-grid with this code:

```
$scope.gridApi.core.handleWindowResize();
```

So the grid resize perfect in LTR, But in RTL it's not working.

[image]

After resize it's looking like this:

[image]

The different between the 2 pictures is that when the menu that show in the first picture, is disappear , the grid column not resize to 100% of the page.

but when this grid is with ltr it is.

Any one has any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to grow up the timeout. some how in ltr it's taking more time...

```
var Add_Wait_To_Resize = $rootScope.Language_Direction == "LTR" ? 100 : 610 ;

            setTimeout(function() {
                 $scope.gridApi.core.handleWindowResize();
               }, Add_Wait_To_Resize);
```